# Since + present perfect

Tags: present-tense

"Since the company downsixed, it's harder to get good internal customer service from Human Resources and Finance."

Shouldn't it be "Since the company downsized, it has been harder to get..."?

I thought we should use the present perfect after the word "since". Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I agree, though you might *just* be able to read the first *since* (with *it's*) as *because*.

Comment: *Since*: "from the time"; also, *since*: "because" -- so there. The original is just as right as your alternate. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, kris. So, if we want to use "since" like " because", present perfect is not necessary. Got it. Cheers.

Comment: @TomLee, which meaning did you intend?

Comment: Tom, start a name with the "at" symbol like so: @kris so that they will get a notification about your comment. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. Your second sentence is better.

> Since the company downsized, it has been harder to get...

The present perfect tells us about something that was true in the past and continues to be true in the present, which is what you want to say here.

The second part of your first sentence in contrast ("it's harder to get") only tells us about the present, which is not what you are trying to say since you are telling us about something that has been true since some particular time in the past.